# iTextSharp Multithread on PdfReader goes into dead end

Tags: c#, multithreading

In our production server, we create thousands of pdf documents by wkhtmltopdf and sign them via iTextSharp using HSM. Most of the operation performed at night. But after we performed an update for multithreading we have been stack into a serious situation. After working a long time, our WCF service starts to give exception for every request:

```
System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Probable I/O race condition detected while copying memory. The I/O package is not thread safe by default. In multithreaded applications, a stream must be accessed in a thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper returned by TextReader's or TextWriter's Synchronized methods. This also applies to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader. 
 at System.Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(Array src, Int32 srcOffsetBytes, Array dst, Int32 dstOffsetBytes, Int32 byteCount
 at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count
 at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String value
 at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(IRandomAccessSource byteSource, Boolean partialRead, Byte[] ownerPassword, X509Certificate certificate, ICipherParameters certificateKey, Boolean closeSourceOnConstructorError
 at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader..ctor(RandomAccessFileOrArray raf, Byte[] ownerPassword, Boolean partial
 at Turkkep.Daemons.Crypto.PDFSignerService.sign(Byte[] sourceData, Stream destination
 at Turkkep.Daemons.Crypto.PDFSignerService.Sign(Byte[] sourceData) Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message) Exception rethrown at [0]: at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg
 at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type
 at Turkkep.Core.Signature.IPDFSigner.Sign(Byte[] sourceData
 at Turkkep.Shared.Signature.PDFSigner.Sign(Byte[] sourceData)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at Turkkep.Shared.Signature.PDFSigner.Sign(Byte[] sourceData
 at Turkkep.Shared.Daemon.InvoiceWorker.getPdfDocument(InvoiceType12 ublInvoice, Int64 organization
 at Turkkep.Shared.Daemon.InvoiceWorker.processEArchive(Invoice invoice, String signedInvoice, InvoiceType12 ublInvoice
 at Turkkep.Shared.Daemon.InvoiceWorker.sendInvoice12(Invoice invoice)
```

Our signing code for WCF service is;

```
    private void sign(byte[] sourceData, Stream destination)
    {
        RandomAccessFileOrArray source = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(sourceData);
        using (var reader = new PdfReader(source, null))
        {
            using (var stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, destination, '\0'))
            {
                var appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
                appearance.Reason = _reason;
                appearance.Location = _location;
                appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), 1, String.Format("TurkKEP-{0}-{1}-{2}", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day));
                var externalSigner = new PDFExternalSigner("SHA-256");

                ICollection<X509Certificate> chain = getChain(externalSigner.GetActiveConnection());

                MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, externalSigner, chain, null, null, null, _estimatedSize, CryptoStandard.CMS);
            }
        }
    }

    public byte[] Sign(byte[] sourceData)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream destination = new MemoryStream())
            {
                sign(sourceData, destination);
                return destination.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch (FaultException)
        {
            throw;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("PDFSignerService.Sign", ex);
            throw new Exception(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
```

I think locking the PdfReader can solve the problem but I don't want to weak multithread power. Getting an exception for some messages is not a problem. In this situation service never works again until we restart it.

Note: Production server is up to date. We've just updated.

**Edit:** Last night we have caught similar exception with different stacktrace:

```
    19.12.2017 04:03:08 
System.Exception: PDF sign failed. Crypto service communication exception occured.
     ---> System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Probable I/O race condition detected while copying memory. The I/O package is not thread safe by default. In multithreaded applications, a stream must be accessed in a thread-safe way, such as a thread-safe wrapper returned by TextReader's or TextWriter's Synchronized methods. This also applies to classes like StreamWriter and StreamReader.
     at System.Buffer.InternalBlockCopy(Array src, Int32 srcOffsetBytes, Array dst, Int32 dstOffsetBytes, Int32 byteCount
     at System.IO.StreamWriter.Write(Char[] buffer, Int32 index, Int32 count
     at System.IO.TextWriter.SyncTextWriter.WriteLine(String value
     at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.Close(PdfIndirectReference info, Int32 skipInfo
     at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfStamperImp.Close(IDictionary`2 moreInfo
     at iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance.PreClose(Dictionary`2 exclusionSizes
     at iTextSharp.text.pdf.security.MakeSignature.SignDetached(PdfSignatureAppearance sap, IExternalSignature externalSignature, ICollection`1 chain, ICollection`1 crlList, IOcspClient ocspClient, ITSAClient tsaClient, Int32 estimatedSize, CryptoStandard sigtype, SignaturePolicyIdentifier signaturePolicy
     at Turkkep.Daemons.Crypto.PDFSignerService.sign(Byte[] sourceData, Stream destination
     at Turkkep.Daemons.Crypto.PDFSignerService.Sign(Byte[] sourceData) Server stack trace: at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.ThrowIfFaultUnderstood(Message reply, MessageFault fault, String action, MessageVersion version, FaultConverter faultConverter
     at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.HandleReply(ProxyOperationRuntime operation, ProxyRpc& rpc
```

After this exception service throws same exception for every call.

Now we are going to change code as following for moving the PdfStamper out of the `using` block.

```
private void sign(byte[] sourceData, Stream destination)
{
    RandomAccessFileOrArray source = new RandomAccessFileOrArray(sourceData);
    using (var reader = new PdfReader(source, null))
    {
        try
        {
            var stamper = PdfStamper.CreateSignature(reader, destination, '\0');
            var appearance = stamper.SignatureAppearance;
            appearance.Reason = _reason;
            appearance.Location = _location;
            appearance.SetVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(0, 0, 0, 0), 1, String.Format("TurkKEP-{0}-{1}-{2}", DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day));
            var externalSigner = new PDFExternalSigner("SHA-256");

            ICollection<X509Certificate> chain = getChain(externalSigner.GetActiveConnection());

            MakeSignature.SignDetached(appearance, externalSigner, chain, null, null, null, _estimatedSize, CryptoStandard.CMS);
            stamper.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.Error("Document sign failed unexpectedly.", ex);
            throw new FaultException("Document sign failed unexpectedly. Exception: " + ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: seems llke IO issue ..when two thread trying to write same file ...where is code of writing to PDF

Comment: We don't write to a file. We call "public byte[] Sign(byte[] sourceData)" method..

Comment: The exception is raised inside constructor of PdfReader which will access the sourceData array in some way. Maybe it is a bug in PdfReader or the bug is in your code which is calling the sign method we do not see

Comment: sign method is a private method and it is called only from the public Sign method.

Comment: ... which is calling the **Sign** method we do not see.

Comment: This is a WCF service class self hosted in a windows service. It is called externally from another process.

Comment: Check the reference of sourceData array. Maybe you are using it multiple times for different data concurrently

Comment: References in WCF cannot be same between calls. This not the case. Also I can accept failure in some calls. In our case service works clearly for a long time (4-5 hours), processes thousands of messages (50000+) then at some point stops working and starts to give same exception to all calls.

Comment: Well if you know that you did not have a bug in your code, why do you ask here? The exception is raised from PdfReader so there must be the/a bug. Report it at iTextSharp issue tracker

Comment: Noone here will care if it is an urgent problem or not. We only see a question and decide if we like to help or not. I am now out from here. Good luck

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/161427/discussion-between-suleyman-oz-and-sir-rufo).

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions (and comments).

Comment: Pro tip: please refrain from telling people to "read the question carefully". To a native English speaker, this is rude and patronising, and you're lucky not to have been downvoted for it. Keep it diplomatic and positive please `:-)`.

Comment: (The best thing I would suggest is to rebuild the server using the old version of your software i.e. minus the multithreading update. At least this will get you going again).